# Why are REST API date $filters being treated differently for certain users?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

We're querying the api/web/lists/GetByTitle('xxx')/items endpoint in SPO and trying to apply $filter to a date field.  For some users the date string needs to be in the 2016-09-05T05:00:00.000Z format and others the 09-05-2016 format.  Why?

Example:

```
api/web/lists/GetByTitle('xxx')/items?$select=Id,cdpv,ResourceId,Hours,ProjectId&$filter=(ResourceId eq ‘9’) and (cdpv eq ‘2016-09-05T05:00:00.000Z’)&$top=5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving this today.  For some reason when we call this API with cdpv eq ‘10-10-2016’, it's fine in our time zone (CST).  But in PST, it doesn't work.  Had to change it to bracket the day and pay attention to time stamps even though the cdvp column is a date only date/time column.

Example:
api/web/lists/GetByTitle('xxx')/items?$select=Id,cdpv,ResourceId,Hours,ProjectId&$filter=(ResourceId eq ‘9’) and (cdpv ge ‘10-10-2016’) and (cdpv lt ‘10-11-2016’)&$top=5000